# handling image view position in chat activity

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

In my app when a user sends or receives images if the user scrolls away from that image and scroll back to it the image becomes invisible leaving it's last position empty thereby messing up the view. the image reappears when the user closes the `ChatActivity`and reopens it.

So my question now is how can i make the image remain at it's position at all times even if a user scrolls to the top and back?

this is my sent message holder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="11:40"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryy"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text_message_body" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sent_message_bubble"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="hello, hello!"
    android:textColor="#080000"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/read_reciept"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:text="seen"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_sent_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sent_message_bubble"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the message adapter

```
 void bind(Messages message) {

            String user_id = message.getFrom();
            String message_type = message.getType();

            boolean seen = message.isSeen();



            if (message_type.equals("text")) {

                if (seen){
                    readReciept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    readReciept.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                messageText.setText(message.getMessage());
                // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
                timeText.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(message.getTime()));
                mSentImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                messageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(mSentImage.getContext()).load(message.getMessage()).into(mSentImage);
   }
```

Comment: Put another variable in your model that keeps track of it and then in your adapter set the image placement with that variable. (In an if-statement or something)

Comment: It has to do with you list . Keep the url in the list when you send a image or receive a image . say imageUrl .

Comment: please can you show an example?